# SwiftUI TextField with format: .number crashes when empty, IntegerParseStrategy

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an `Asset` SwiftData object with `var cost: Int?` in it.

I have this TextField() in my View:

```
TextField("realestate_cost_eg", value: $asset.cost, format: .number)
```

If `$asset.cost = nil`, as soon as this TextField gets focus the app crashes due to an `IntegerParseStrategy.parse()` error.

I know there are a lot of other questions/answers out there that refer to `TextField(formatter: NumberFormatter())` solutions, but that initializer isn't the recommended approach anymore. The recommended init is `TextField(value: , format:)`.

And the documentation explicitly says this should work as I would expect it to work, i.e. it takes a binding to an optional, whenever the text changes it will try to parse it and set the value on the binding, but if it can't parse it then it sets the value on the binding to nil:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield/init(_:value:format:prompt:)-6ug7k

> Use this initializer to create a text field that binds to a bound
> optional value, using a ParseableFormatStyle to convert to and from
> this type. Changes to the bound value update the string displayed by
> the text field. Editing the text field updates the bound value, as
> long as the format style can parse the text. If the format style can’t
> parse the input, the text field sets the bound value to nil.

Instead, if `$asset.cost` is nil and the TextField() gets focus, then my app crashes with this stacktrace:

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this using Xcode 15.1 RC

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you for trying. I just created a new, bare project and it worked as I would expect it to work. So there must be something else in my project causing it to spiral out. I'll keep looking.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Ohhhhh, I think I know what's happening. I've got the Swift Error Breakpoint enabled in Xcode and when the textfield gets focus, it's breaking on the Swift Error Breakpoint. But if I click Continue twice it'll get through it and behave as expected. I thought it was crashing, but it was just breaking on the Swift Error Breakpoint in a place that didn't make any sense. But it's essentially an ignorable error.

Comment: If you think about it, a text entry box on screen just cannot possibly work with an optional. Maybe you can remove the need for an optional higher up in your data flow? E.g. don't even allow an `Asset` to exist without a `cost`. Or only make an Asset after your form fields have valid data in their own states and copy from those to a new Asset.

Comment: @malhal It does make perfect sense to have a textfield with an optional number. An empty string is nil. Which is actually how the whole thing is documented to work and -does- work... but internally it's throwing (and catching) some Swift Error. Xcode was just hitting the Swift Error breakpoint at the deep recesses of Apple's code, even though that Error was being caught. That's what gave me the false impression that it was crashing.